# ¿Cómo filtrar en un datatable mediante el cambio de un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

¿Cómo se podría personalizar para filtrar en el plugin datatable, con un checkbox?

Dejar un checkbox que permita filtrar por un campo de la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma puede ser usando eventos, con JQuery se hace facilmente de la siguiente forma:

Cuando creas el datable, guardas la instancia en una variable. Para el ejemplo es `$dataTable`:

```
var $dataTable = $("#id_datable").dataTable();
```

Luego te suscribes a cada cambio del checkbox y filtras con el metodo `fnFilter` de datatables, la variable `columnIndex` es el índice de la columna, si no lo especificas filtrará en todas las columnas.

```
$('input[name="my_checkbox"]').change(function(){
   if(this.checked) {
      $dataTable.fnFilter("Texto a filtrar", columnIndex );
   }
   else {
      $dataTable.fnFilter("", columnIndex );
   }
});
```

No está probado, pero es la idea.